# Android Design - mimicing a the numpad with linear layouts

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-button

**code is here: http://pastebin.com/4RFUtYgt**

I want to mimic the numpad in an android activity. I have set up 9 buttons and put each grouping of a horiziontal 3 in a linear layout. There are three of them.

When I look at the graphical layout, they are all on top of eachother.

How do I fix this and mimic the look that I want?

edit: This is what my goal project should be close to:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/54zAX.jpg

Comment: It's because your layout root element is a RelativeLayout. Replace that with a LinearLayout and it should work. Whether or not that is a good approach is debatable, especially if you're targeting multiple screen sizes. I'd just go with a relative layout and position the linear layouts relative to one another.

Comment: can you show the design of your view what you want to create?? it will help full??

Comment: http://imgur.com/YdwWdwd is my supposed end goal

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make Android layout mimic a KeyPad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23176909/make-android-layout-mimic-a-keypad)